# creating a hollow rectangle

Tags: c++

My assignment is to allow for user input of width, height, and character, in order to create a hollow rectangle. I am hitting a wall in my coding, For some reason, my rectangle doesn't have a "top" and the right side isn't on the correct column. I am fairly new to C++, so any criticism you may have is welcomed!

Below is my code and the output that I receive.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, j, height, width;
char ch;
char cont ='Y';
while (cont=='Y' || cont=='y')
{
cout << "Enter desired height (3 to 20): ";
cin >> height;
while (height > 20 || height < 3 )
{
    cout<<"Illegal entry. Please enter height value from 3 to 20: ";
    cin >> height;
}

cout <<"Enter desired width (3 to 20): ";
cin >> width;
while (width > 20 || width < 3)
{
    cout<<"Illegal entry. Please enter width value from 3 to 20: ";
    cin >> width;
}

cout << "What character would you like to set as your border?: ";
cin >> ch;

for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
   if(width <= 1)
   for(int i = 1; i <=width; i++) {
                cout << " " << ch;
            }
        else if(i < height) {
            cout << endl;
                for(int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
                            if(j == 1 || j == width)
                                cout << " " << ch;
                            else
                                cout << " ";
                                                }
                            }
                else {
                cout<< endl;
                    for(int k = 1; k <= width; k++)
                        {
                        cout <<" "<< ch;
                        }
                    }
                                    }



cout<<"\nDo you want to continue? (Y): ";
cin >> cont;
}
 cout <<"\nYou are done here, good job.\n";
 cout <<'\n';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Two variable called `i`, one inside the other? That is horrible, How about calling one `row` and the other `column` - that will remind you what you are doing and may help find the issue(s). As for the top line? You have no code to draw it. Why would you expect it to be there? What is the point of `if(width <= 1)` ? you already know it is >=3

Comment: Unrelated: You may find it a lot easier to follow your code if you follow a bracketing and indention scheme. I find the [Allman Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) to be very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to below result when assign height and width is 4.

```
* * * *
*     *
*     *
* * * *
```

your for loop is wrong, using this code in your for loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
  if( i == 1 || i == height) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
      std::cout << ch << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
   } else {
    for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
      if( j == 1 || j == width) {
        std::cout << ch << " ";
      } else {
        std::cout << "  ";
      }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend explaining what was wrong, highlighting your changes, and explaining how your changes fixed the problem. If you don't, you have provided a code-only answer and they are generally good for little more than levelling up one's copy and paste skills.

Answer (score 1):

While I won't get into the code itself, think about what you want to accomplish first, and then write the loops. (I suggest using `row` and `col` as variable names.)

Since you need a hollow rectangle and you are taking in a desired `width` and `height` we know the following (`w` and `h` being input amounts.)

So do the following prints in order:

1. You need a row of `*` with length `w`.
2. You need `h - 2` rows of `*` that have `w - 2` spaces between them.
3. You need another row like 1.

Do these in order and you will have your hollow rectangle.

Example input: `w = 5, h = 7`.

So we have:

```
***** // Step 1.
*   * // Step 2. Note there are 5 - 2 spaces between them. (w - 2). 
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
***** // Step 3.
```

Comment: This will be a stupid question, but, the first row, of code, will be a "For" loop, correct?

Comment: @Zethos Yes. A loop from `0` to `w` and print a `*` each time.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I don't like to do copy and paste, so you helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have a good answer, you are not making use of the C++ language functions that would make the task much easier, and more importantly, you are not validating your input correctly. For example, try the following:

```
> McNiel CSC 2050.exe
Enter desired height (3 to 20): No, I don't think I will
```

Things go wildly spinning out of control quickly.

Generally, when you want to validate user input and ensure you receive values within a specific range, you simply want a continual loop, where you prompt, validate the input, check/handle the stream states `.eof(), .bad()` and `.fail()` (see: [std::basic_iostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream)) and empty any remaining characters in your input buffer before your next read attempt.

An example for your `h x w` input loop would be similar to the following (note, both `h` and `w` are read at the same time, you are free to use two loops if you like):

```
    int h, w;

    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): ";
        if (!(std::cin >> h >> w)) {
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {
                std::cerr << "(user canceled/unrecoverable error)\n";
                return 1;
            }
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {
                std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }
        }
        else if (3 <= h && h <=20 && 3 <= w && w <= 20)
            break;
        else 
            std::cerr << "error: h or w not within (3 <= x <= 20)\n";
    }
```

See [std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for details on emptying the input stream and [std::basic_ios::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

Next, rather than some loop scheme outputting spaces, you simply need to make use of [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to handle the spacing between the `'*'` to make your hollow rectangle. The top and bottom are solid, but for the middle rows, all you need to do is `std::cout << '*' << std:setw(w-1) << '*';`. For example your entire output loop reduces to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        if (!i || i == h - 1)
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
                std::cout << '*';
        else
            std::cout << '*' << std::setw(w-1) << '*';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {
    int h, w;

    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): ";
        if (!(std::cin >> h >> w)) {
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {
                std::cerr << "(user canceled/unrecoverable error)\n";
                return 1;
            }
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {
                std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }
        }
        else if (3 <= h && h <=20 && 3 <= w && w <= 20)
            break;
        else 
            std::cerr << "error: h or w not within (3 <= x <= 20)\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        if (!i || i == h - 1)
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
                std::cout << '*';
        else
            std::cout << '*' << std::setw(w-1) << '*';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hollowrect
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): No, I don't think I will
error: invalid integer input.
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): OK
error: invalid integer input.
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): 10 2
error: h or w not within (3 <= x <= 20)
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): 10 3
***
* *
* *
* *
* *
* *
* *
* *
* *
***
```

A second `h x w` example:

```
$ ./bin/hollowrect
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): 3 10
**********
*        *
**********
```

User cancels with manual `EOF`:

```
$ ./bin/hollowrect
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): help
error: invalid integer input.
enter height & width (3 <= h w <= 20): (user canceled/unrecoverable error)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Whoa, firstly, this is crazy and I really appreciate the input you've given me! I just started my CSC 2050 class this semester, so we are going over the basics right now. However, what you've given me looks really interesting and I'll have to save it for later use! My Prof. didn't give us any book info, figured we could all look it up ourselves; I don't suppose you would have any advice on books I could get to do better research with?

Comment: Bookmark [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and spend the time it takes to get familiar with it. (generally looking through it by "Headers" (as you get to them in your class) is a good way to get a feel for what is available). Good luck with your coding.